# Scaling quiver plot of vector field with axis in figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector, plot

This is the plot of my vector field:

[image: initial plot]

I want the vectors of a velocity field to be evenly spaced throughout this figure, instead of being squished together in the x direction, and stretched out in the y direction.

I think I know why it goes wrong, but how do I make it go right?
Here is the relevant part of the code.

```
slice_interval = 10
skip = slice(None, None, slice_interval)
plt.quiver(x[skip], y[skip], u[skip], v[skip])
```

**Update**

Based on the suggested solution, doing `x[skip][skip]`, etc..., did not solve the issue. If anything it actually made it worse. But it may provide some possibilities to tinker around with, maybe different skips for each of the axes?  I'll try to tinker around with it some on my own.

New graph after trying suggested solution:

[image: wrong solution implementation]

**New Update**

I did not implement the solution correctly the first time, after a lot of fiddling I now get a beautiful velocity field plot, thanks a lot for the help and encouragement, in particular xg.plt.py for the solution.

Corrected plot:

[image: correct plot]

Comment: And why do you think it goes wrong?

Comment: Also, please don't apologize for being a noob, especially when you make the effort to ask a well posed question like this one. There is no shame in beginning something, and usually you will be given a chance to fix what's wrong before you get burned. Good work and welcome to SO.

Comment: I am now less confident that I knew why it was going wrong.. I think I'm just gonna have to leave this as it is, and go back to understand quiver plots more thoroughly later on from bottom up, with some simpler plots than this.

Comment: Please add the following info to your question: x.shape, y.shape, u.shape, v.shape (I'm assuming they are all the same), and the exact code you ran to get the second plot. I think I know what the problem is, but I need to confirm.

Comment: The reason I ask for exact code is because you show `x[skip][skip]`, which it **not** the same as `x[skip, skip]`.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my first post, I did not implement the solution correctly, it now works as it should!

Comment: I have updated the answer to explain the difference between `[skip][skip]` and `[skip, skip]` and added a plot of all the behaviours

Comment: @HELLOKITTY. The standard procedure here would be to select the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it. This will get you and the xg some points, and will remove your question from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them to be evenly spaced both in x and y axis, you have to slice the input arrays in both of their dimensions. Otherwise, you are slicing per rows.

The only line that needs to be changed is:

```
plt.quiver(x[skip,skip], y[skip,skip], u[skip,skip], v[skip,skip])
```

### Edit

As pointed out in the comments, another option is to define `skip2 = (slice(None, None, slice_interval),) * 2` and slicing the arrays directly with `array[skip2]` gives exactly the same result.

A different case is doing `array[skip][skip]`. In this case, the slicing is applied and then the result of the first slice is sliced again, the second `[skip]` is not applied to the second axis of the array but instead _at the first axis of `array[skip]`. Step by step it is doing:

```
# we start from array.shape = (110, 100)
a2 = array[skip]
# Intermediate step: a2.shape = (11, 100) # containing rows 0, 10, 20...
a3 = a2[skip]
# Final output: a3.shape = (2,100) # now we have sliced every 10 rows of a2
# which translated to array means slicing every 100 rows and still keeping all the columns.
```

Below there is a plot showing each of the interesting cases (both u and v are set to 1 so that all vectors are equal, and the meshgrid is created with a 100 dots linspace between 0 and 100 in x and 110 dots between -50 and 50 in y)

[image: slicing options]

Comment: Well seen. 2D arrays need 2D indices.

Comment: If saving characters is an issue to where `x[::slice_interval, ::slice_interval]` is an issue, you can keep the original indexing expression but redefine `skip` as `skip = (slice(None, None, slice_interval),) * 2`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it looked very reasonable, but unfortunately it did not give the result I desired, I'll post the new graph I got below.